# Definitive list of available Angular material classes

Tags: angular-material

If find that the angular material docs are horrendous,the examples are great.While searching for solutions for various issues I spot md classes I've never seen before.

`md-fling md-mini md-toolbar-tools md-accent`

Is there a place where I can get a proper list of all available classes I can use in angular material,would make live so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found such a resource. I generally prefer Chrome but in this case I find opening a page in Firefox that references angular-material.css (or the minified version) and then navigating to the style editor in the inspector provides a pretty nice view of all of the available classes.